# How to overload an operator == inside an other class

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a class A

In a template class B

```
template<class key>
class B
```

I want to overload the ==operator of A inside the class B, because I don't want it to be overloaded outside the class

how can I do that?

I tried:

1.

```
bool operator==(const key &a, const key &b)
```

compilation result: too many arguments

2.

```
friend operator==(const key &a, const key &b)
```

when I tried to use the operator, compilation result: can't find operator

Comment: How about defining the operator in a private namespace then `using` it inside `B`'s member functions definitions?

Comment: @Quentin thought about this solution, but i don’t think it’s elegant enough

Answer (score 3):

You can define a nested private wrapper for your key type:

```
template<class key>
class B
{
    struct EKey {
        key k;
        friend bool operator==(const EKey&, const EKey&) { return false; }
    };
    // ...
};
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fd8e570f2b12a3e